# Need to implement Filter, criteria spring data

Tags: sql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a table `User` which have a collections of `Role` and collections of `City`.

I need to implement filter logic like this **/?cities=LA,Berlin&roles=Admin** that returns Users with `{LA and Berlin and other if it has}` and role `{Admin}`

```
SELECT * FROM user

LEFT JOIN user_city
ON user.id = user_city.user_id
LEFT JOIN city
ON city.id = user_city.city_id

WHERE city.name in ('LA','Berlin')  
GROUP BY 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

It works for one criteria how to make with two and more? 
I need make it on criteria spring data but better would be understand how it works in sql first.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM user

LEFT JOIN user_city
ON user.id = user_city.user_id
LEFT JOIN city
ON city.id = user_city.city_id

WHERE city.name in ('LA','Berlin')  
AND roles= 'Admin'
GROUP BY 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```